# Namespace: How do you distinguish duplicate function names, one/respective .swift file?

Tags: swift, namespaces

Hypothetical scenario: two .swift files (one.swift & two.swift), both have the function (or any other entity):

```
func doSomething() {
}
```

How would you differentiate one's doSomething() from two's doSomething()?

BTW: both .swift files are within the same Xcode target.

This is purely hypothetical for edification.

Comment: Given two top-level functions, you can't.   Hole em up in structs as static methods and use that to fake a namespace.

Comment: I can build the app, however the func within the nearest scope gets called, ignoring the duplicate in the other .swift file.  Hence, as you say, wrap them in their respective struct.

Comment: it is not good idea and should not be done.I think you should file radar as compiler should give the error if two global function with same name is defined in same module

Comment: I tried again; this time the compiler noticed the error and flagged it.    So ...I blame this on gremlins.

Answer (score 2):

You can not able to create if both same name top level functions are in same taget.You may want to put them in `struct` as `static` functions so you can access by `struct` name.

```
struct MyStruct {

    static func doSomething() {
    }
}

//acess by struct name
MyStruct.doSomething()
```

If they both are in different `target` or `modules` and declared as `public` you should access by their `ModuleName`

Comment: I was able to build and run both duplicates.  However the func with the nearest scope is accessed.

Comment: --- Tried after cleansing & rebuilding...this time the compiler had notice the problem and flagged it as an error.   .... so I'll just file this problem under 'gremlins'.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. A bit of refactoring and this was the simple solution.